# display info of pixel after for loop (matlab)

Tags: image, matlab, loops

I am using a for loop over some weather data to indicate severity of a thunderstorm situation, see the code below.
I am wondering now, if I display the image with imagesc(), is there a way that by clicking on the pixel, the reason why this value is assigned will be displayed?
For example, if I click on a pixel with value 1, it would display a text box saying "because 10 < cape < 750 and shear < 20" 
Thanks!

```
for i = 1:size(cape_fin,1)
for j = 1:size(cape_fin,2)
    if cape_fin(i,j) > 10 && cape_fin(i,j) < 750 && shear_fin(i,j) < 20 
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 1;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 10 && cape_fin(i,j) < 750 && shear_fin(i,j) > 20 && shear_fin(i,j) < 40
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 2;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 10 && cape_fin(i,j) < 750 && shear_fin(i,j) > 40
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 3;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 750 && cape_fin(i,j) < 1300 && shear_fin(i,j) > 20 && shear_fin(i,j) < 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) < 6.6 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) < 7.3
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 2;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 750 && cape_fin(i,j) < 1300 && shear_fin(i,j) > 20 && shear_fin(i,j) < 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) > 6.6 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) > 7.3
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 3;    
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 750 && cape_fin(i,j) < 1300 && shear_fin(i,j) > 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) < 6.6 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) < 7.3
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 3;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 750 && cape_fin(i,j) < 1300 && shear_fin(i,j) > 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) > 6.6 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) > 7.3
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 4;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 750 && cape_fin(i,j) < 1300 && shear_fin(i,j) < 20 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) > 7.3 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) > 7.9
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 3;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 750 && cape_fin(i,j) < 1300 && shear_fin(i,j) < 20 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) < 7.3 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) < 7.9
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 2;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 1300 && cape_fin(i,j) < 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) > 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) > 6.6 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) > 7.3
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 4;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 1300 && cape_fin(i,j) < 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) > 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) < 6.6 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) < 7.3
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 3;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 1300 && cape_fin(i,j) < 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) > 20 && shear_fin(i,j) < 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) < 7.3 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) < 7.9
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 3;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 1300 && cape_fin(i,j) < 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) > 20 && shear_fin(i,j) < 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) > 7.3 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) > 7.9
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 3;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 1300 && cape_fin(i,j) < 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) < 20
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 3;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) > 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) > 6.6 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) > 7.3
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 5;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) > 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) < 6.6 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) < 7.3
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 4;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) > 20 && shear_fin(i,j) < 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) < 7.3 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) < 7.9
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 4;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) > 20 && shear_fin(i,j) < 40 && tlr_600_800_fin(i,j) > 7.3 || tlr_500_700_fin(i,j) > 7.9
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 4;
    elseif cape_fin(i,j) > 2000 && shear_fin(i,j) < 20
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 4;
    else
        hail_prob_level_fin(i,j) = 1;
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple starting point example:

The example lets the user select a pixel with the mouse.
Assume pixel coordinates are x,y

1. Read x,y pixel value form original images (`cape_fin` and `shear_fin` in your case).
2. Read x,y pixel value form result image (`hail_prob_level_fin` in your case).
3. Format a text message based on the pixel value of `cape_fin`, `shear_fin` and `hail_prob_level_fin` (format the message as you like...).

**Note that this is not an automatic mechanism as you might looked for - you need to do it patronymically.**

Here is a simplified code sample:

```
A = imread('cameraman.tif'); %Assume A is cape_fin
B = imbinarize(A);   %Assume B is your hail_prob_level_fin (I used imbinarize for simplicity).
figure;imagesc(B); %Display the image (hail_prob_level_fin in your case).
%[x,y,P] = impixel(); %Mark a one pixel, press and press enter (just an example for marking a pixel).

for i = 1:10
    [x,y] = ginput(1); %Let the user select a pixel with the mouse.

    x = round(x);y = round(y); %Round coordinates.

    a = A(y, x); %Get original pixel value (cape_fin in your case, you also need value from shear_fin)
    b = B(y, x); %Get result pixel value (hail_prob_level_fin in your case).

    %Show message box according to value of original and result pixel value:
    waitfor(msgbox(sprintf('B(%d, %d) = %d, because A(%d, %d) = %d', x, y, b, x, y, a)));
end
```

Example for displayed message:
[image]